# Set a Request variable in a tag struts

Tags: struts

In my action:

```
.....
String status = "add";
servletRequest.setAttribute("button", status);
....
```

In my JSP:

```
<c:if test='${button == "add"}'>
  <c:set var="edittype" value="add" />
</c:if>
<c:if test='${button == "update"}'>
  <c:set var="edittype" value="update" />
</c:if>
```

I have tried:

```
<html:hidden property ="" value="edittype" />
```

and

```
<html:hidden property ="" value="${button}" />
```

and niether work. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Two ways

1>

```
    <html:hidden property ="reqButtonValue" value="${param.button}" /> 

    <c:if test="${reqButtonValue=='add'}">
  <c:set var="edittype" value="add" />
</c:if>
```

2>

```
<c:if test="${param.button=='add'}">
      <c:set var="edittype" value="add" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: No, I get: <input type="hidden" name="" value="${param.button}">

Comment: @mike628 Then you're not running in a JSP 2.0 container; use the EL tag library.

Comment: When I do this:<textarea name="subject"  cols=83 rows=2 class="codetext"><c:out value="${button}" /></textarea>  I can access the value